# Error : ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next

Tags: java, jdbc

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" errorPage= "error.jsp"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <%
        /*
        int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
        int k = i + j ;
        out.print(k);*/
        
        String url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/achref";
        String username ="postgres";
        String password ="0";
        String sql="select * from users ";
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.next();
        %>
        <%=rs.getString(2) %>
        
        
        
        
</body>
</html>
```

this is my jsp file, i wanted to create a connection to the postgresql data base but an error keeps telling to call next although i'm already calling it.
help please.

> Error : ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.

Answer (score 0):

One should avoid `select *`, and always use a PreparedStatement (to escape apostrophes and such. And especially prevent hacking: [**SQL injection**](https://xkcd.com/327/).

```
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        // With placeholders "?"
        // st.setString(1, "mois");
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                %><%= rs.getString("name") %><%
                //Alternatively: out.print(rs.getString("name"));
            }
        } // Closes on finally rs.
    } // Closes on finally st and con.
```

The error seems to indicate that there still are no users in the database table.
Then `rs.next()` returns false, and one should not call `rs.getString` from a non-existing record data.